# Highcharts pdf displaying two sets of percentages

Tags: highcharts

I have a script that produces a Highcharts column graph. This working perfectly and display the percentage at the top of each data column.

If I then export it to a PDF using the Highcharts export function the percentage is displayed twice on each column.

Does anyone have any idea why this happends.

As I say the on screen display is fine.

Many thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set textShadow as false, see below :

```
plotOptions: {
series: {
    dataLabels: {
        style: { textShadow: false },
    }
}
}
```

[here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/2ck3ukg6/6/) with your previous question's data

[image: screenshot of pdf exported]

EDIT: Related topic on github: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3649

Comment: once again to the rescue, Many thanks and I am learning fast because of people like you. Perfect